How to save dbgid Ehlib state after open main query
The company I work for them decide to replace all the Delphi dbgrid with Ehlib dbgrid. So in the default way we have qrymain-> dsMain-> dbgrid relation for using the some feature of dbgrid Ehlib  now we have this relation  qryMain->DataSetDriver->memEhTable->dataSource->dbgridEh.
Here comes the problem: ehlib has a search panel user search some thing and data in memory filtered for example to 10 row then select a row an click a button at the end of the button the qrymain open and memory table lost its state and show all record again.
What should I do to just show the 10 records and be on the selected record?
try
     frmRebuildCust.QCust:= MemEhMain;//MemEhMain;
     frmRebuildCust.Grd:=   grdMain;
     mr:= frmRebuildCust.ShowModal;
     if mr = mrOK then
     begin
          MemEhMain.DisableControls;
          try
           qryMain.open;

          finally
            MemEhMain.EnableControls;
          end;
     end;
  finally
     MemEhMain.GotoBookmark(bm); /// here can not find the bookmark because query opened and we have all record
     MemEhMain.FreeBookmark(bm);
     frmRebuildCust.Free;
  end;

A solution that memory table and grid have the state that have before like filtered with the same count of rows.
